# How to run a service as daemon in Centos 5

Tags: centos, daemon

In Ubuntu, I use `-D` to run a service as daemon. I wonder there is any similar command to do this in Centos.

Comment: What thing are you trying to run as a service?

Answer (score 1):

-D can only be used if the applications supports that. If the application you intend to daemonise in Ubuntu is via -D option then it should work the same way in Centos Also.

Comment: Thanks, but i found the solution by using `nohup` with the command and end up with `&`